# The future of JAVA because of the new Oracle license update?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am refering to the [link](https://java.com/en/download/release_notice.jsp)

> Public updates for Oracle Java SE 8 released after January 2019 will not be available for business, commercial or production use without a commercial license.

Java is Open Source for sure, maybe The Community will release OpenJDKs updates, but i still have my worries about this news...

I really would like to know about your opinions, and if we imagine the worst case (wich i do not hope), that Oracle do the same with the others new java versions...
What are the solutions ?

Comment: What exactly are you afraid of?

Comment: While links are nice as *additional* resource, it can't be only (and mandatory to visit) info about problem/subject you are asking about. Place all relevant parts in the question itself.

Comment: It is done ! :)

Comment: I am afraid about making the new updates of JAVA 8 (wich i think that it is a lot used in the JAVA world) commercial, but apparently most languages don’t have a long term support model for older releases

Comment: Afraid this will likely soon get closed as off-topic; you're specifically asking people's opinions, which doesn't make it a great fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The link you are referring to looks to me like a normal Java version lifecycle announcement.  Each version of Java SE eventually stops receiving public updates, and by that time, there is a newer Java SE in wide use.

See [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html) and [Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

Comment: Ok Thanks, i thought it was new to make updates commercials, for a non commercial based Java version wich is Java 8

Comment: I do not think this is a 'normal' lifecycle announcement. Posters say OpenJDK and IBM Java will be available longer. https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/8d9hcg/public_updates_for_oracle_java_se_8_released/ For jenkins, which uses java server, I think they have a ticket to upgrade. https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203601234-CloudBees-Jenkins-Platform-Supported-Java-Versions